# App crashes on macOS 10.13 with "DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing" despite symbol being wrapped in @available(macOS 10.14.4, *)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

There is exactly one occurrence of symbol `kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptedKey` in my Objective-C project. It is surrounded by an `@available` block:

```
if (@available(macOS 10.14.4, *)) {
    CFStringRef x = kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptedKey;
}
```

Yet the program crashes on macOS 10.13:

```
Date/Time:             2023-10-18 19:37:34.273 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C780E8BB-9F5C-A7EC-2846-AD51F8D2912C


Time Awake Since Boot: 2700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptedKey
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/AvailableCrash.app/Contents/MacOS/AvailableCrash
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
 in /Users/USER/Desktop/AvailableCrash.app/Contents/MacOS/AvailableCrash
```

I'm running Xcode 15.0 (15A240d) on macOS 13.6 (22G120). The program runs as expected on this development machine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it crashing on app launch or at certain point?

Comment: It crashes on startup while loading the symbols. main() is never reached.

Comment: In yours surrounded block mentioned `kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptionDetailKey`, but system is arguing for `kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptedKey`

Comment: You have keen eyes! Alas, this was only a copy/paste error. I have modified the question. Thank you very much for pointing this out!

Comment: Just adding a reference to this issue https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/68163#issuecomment-1728212881 (should have been solved with xcode 15.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 15.0 has some bugs related to weak-linking (i.e. symbols not being weak-linked when they should), here is [one I found](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/569) in PyObjC.

Try Xcode15.1b1, if that doesn't fix the issue then file a feedback with Apple. And in the meantime, keep building your shipping application with Xcode 14.

Comment: Thank you so much! Xcode 15.1beta (15C5028h) fixes this issue. There are other issues with weak linking, though. I have filed a bug report (FB13289462).

Comment: There is a flag, -ld_classic, (add ```-Wl,-ld_classic``` to OTHER_LDFLAGS) which can force use of the old linker with Xcode 15, which may let you use Xcode 15. Not sure that will work if going back to Xcode 14; you can conditionally add for just sdk=iphoneos17* or sdk-iphonesimulator17* if you need to flip between Xcodes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reference the symbol. Use hardcoded value `DAMediaEncrypted` within the macro block and see if it helps.

```
(lldb) po kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptionDetailKey
DAMediaEncryptionDetail
(lldb) po kDADiskDescriptionMediaEncryptedKey
DAMediaEncrypted
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. I chose this example for brevity, to construct a minimal example which reproduces the problem. Actually I am using a different functionality.